# Is there CSS for typesetting the LaTeX logo in HTML?

Tags: css, latex

I'm looking for css equivalent to the `\LaTeX` macro that will produce a beautifully typeset LaTeX logo within an HTML document via css. That is,

`<p>This web site uses <span class="latex">LaTeX</span> to generate the PDF version of this web page.</p>`

The CSS probably should replace the roman characters TeX with Greek (and use the right font via web fonts if possible) etc.

Surely I can not be the first person to want to do this …

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A Google search lead me to [TeX and LaTeX logo POSHlets](http://edward.oconnor.cx/2007/08/tex-poshlet).

The solution involves:

```css
    .tex sub, .latex sub, .latex sup {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .tex sub, .latex sub {
      vertical-align: -0.5ex;
      margin-left: -0.1667em;
      margin-right: -0.125em;
    }

    .tex, .latex, .tex sub, .latex sub {
      font-size: 1em;
    }

    .latex sup {
      font-size: 0.85em;
      vertical-align: 0.15em;
      margin-left: -0.36em;
      margin-right: -0.15em;
    }
```

```html
<p><span class="tex">T<sub>e</sub>X</span> and 
<span class="latex">L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span></p>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Is there a way to get the XeLaTeX logo? This would involve mirroring the first E.

Comment: @StefanMüller, linking to your answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562282/is-there-css-for-typesetting-the-xelatex-logo-in-html?rq=1