# Is there CSS for typesetting the XeLaTeX logo in HTML?

Tags: css, latex, xelatex

I want to use the XeLaTeX logo in HTML pages. I found the answer to a similar question regarding the LaTeX logo here: 
[Is there CSS for typesetting the LaTeX logo in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160514/is-there-css-for-typesetting-the-latex-logo-in-html), but the XeLaTeX logo involves a mirrored E. Is there a trick to get this too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use “Ǝ” U+018E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER REVERSED E to get a mirrored E, but it’s tricky and risky to do a character substitution with CSS.

So a better approach would be to uppercase the “e” and use a 3D transform. Considering just this part, the following code would work on sufficiently modern browsers:

```
<style>
.revcap {
display: inline-block;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
X<span class=revcap>e</span>LaTeX
```

Comment: OK. The following seems to work then for the whole problem. `<span class="latex">X<sub><span class=revcap>e</span></sub>L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span>`Thanks a lot!